# change style of one element without changeing the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, styles

sorry the question doesnt make sense but i shall explain.
I have two hyperlinks

```
<a href="" class="menu-link">home</a>
<a href="" class="menu-link">blog</a>
```

i want to apply this style

```
<style>
.menu-link{color:#000;}
</style>
```

but only apply to `<a href="" class="menu-link">home</a>` how can this be done other than actually changing the class like below

```
<a href="" class="menu-link-1">home</a>
<a href="" class="menu-link-2">blog</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're unable to modify the markup to add an additional class, you can select an element it by its `href` attribute, assuming it has one:

```
a.menu-link[href='home.html'] {
  color: #000;
}
```

[Here's a live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/j3NzW/3/)

Answer (score 4):

You can assign multiple class to a single element.

```
<a href="" class="menu-link home">home</a>
<a href="" class="menu-link">blog</a>
```

all you need is add a space

```
<style>
.menu-link.home{color:#000;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't / won't change the actual markup, try this (jQuery)

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var home = $("a.menu-link:contains('home')");

    // change style
    home.css("color", "#000");

    // add class
    home.addClass("other-class");

    // remove class
    home.removeClass("menu-link");

    // add / change attributes
    home.attr("id", "some-id");        
});
```

Comment: instead of `.css("color", "#000");`  is to possible to apply an id or change the class?

Comment: @user1010031 definitely. Once you have the element by the selector, you can do whatever you want to it

Comment: how? what is the actuall jquery for it?

Comment: @user1010031 If you don't need to support IE6 and your links actually have `href` attributes, Michael's answer is *much* nicer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solution will fit your needs.

```
<a href="" class="menu-link black">home</a>
<a href="" class="menu-link">blog</a>

<style>
.menu-link{}
.black {color:#000;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Alt 1

You could add a `style` attribute to that anchor:

```
<a href="" class="menu-link" style="color:#000;">home</a>
```

### Alt 2

Or you could add an `id` to that anchor:

```
<a href="" class="menu-link" id="specialstyle">home</a>
```

, and replace `.menu-link` with `#specialstyle` in your css.

### Alt 3

Or you could give that anchor an additional `class`:

```
<a href="" class="menu-link menu-link-special">home</a>
```

, and replace `.menu-link` with `.menu-link-special` in your css.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another class to `menu-link-1` with the style you want:

```
<style>a.home { color: #000; }</style>
<a href="" class="menu-link-1 home">home</a>
<a href="" class="menu-link-2">blog</a>
```

**edit**: obviously, if I read the question, I would have noticed that the author didn't want to change the classes..

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that the 'home' link is the first one in these sequence so why not use

```
.menu-link { color: <your_default_color>; }
.menu-link:first-child { color: #000; }
```