# How can I change a button color without changing all the other buttons color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Let say I have 100 buttons or radio buttons on a grid and some of them are clicked/checked and present a certain color (let say green). How can I change the color of the next button I click on without changing the color of the buttons already checked? Cause, I'm a bit lazy defining a hundred different classes on my .css file for each button... :p

PS: I work on vue.js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change style of one element without changeing the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883760/change-style-of-one-element-without-changeing-the-other)

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the css just like in the below approach

```js
var app = new Vue({
 el:"#app",
 methods: {
  setColor(event) {
   console.log(event.target);
   for(let buttonEle of event.currentTarget.children) {
    buttonEle.style.color = 'black';
    buttonEle.style.background = 'white';
    buttonEle.boxShadow = 'none';
    event.target.border = 'black';
   }
   event.target.style.color = 'white';
   event.target.style.background = 'blue';
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="button-container" @click="setColor">
    <button>A</button>
    <button>B</button>
    <button>C</button>
    <button>D</button>
  </div>
</div>
```